# GetConsoleSelectionInfo C++

Tags: c++, console

cI want to select some text with my cursor using the Mark Function from Console, but my code doesn't work ...

```
CONSOLE_SELECTION_INFO c;
if(GetConsoleSelectionInfo(&c))
{
    while((c.dwFlags & CONSOLE_MOUSE_DOWN) == 0) { if(c.dwFlags) cout << c.dwFlags; } 

    cout << "SelectionAnchor: " << c.dwSelectionAnchor.X << " " << c.dwSelectionAnchor.Y;
    cout << "RectangleSelection: " << c.srSelection.Top << " " << c.srSelection.Left << c.srSelection.Bottom << c.srSelection.Right;
}
else cout << "\n\nError:  " << GetLastError();
```

Whatever I'm selecting or I'm doing, always c.dwFlags will be 0 ...

Comment: Nowhere does the documentation for `GetConsoleSelectionInfo` say you can call it once and the data will be automatically updated after that. It says you call it and it fills in data.

Comment: Show me an example, please!